# Get output of process without forbidden api

Tags: java, gradle, binaries

I'm trying to get the output of a process that executes a binary file like this:

```java
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] command = new String[]{this.binaryPath, text};
Process p = rt.exec(command);
Scanner s = new Scanner(p.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
String output = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
```

However when I build my project with Gradle, I get an error saying:

> Task :forbiddenApisMain FAILED
>   Forbidden method invocation: java.util.Scanner#(java.io.InputStream) [Uses default charset]

Apparently something I'm doing is forbidden by Gradle. What is it and what are my alternatives here so Gradle doesn't complain?

Comment: The method itself is not forbidden, but using it without an explicit charset is. Try using [`java.util.Scanner#(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-java.lang.String-) instead.

Comment: @Mtcoster yep that works. Thank you.